# Mockito when any java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: elasticsearch, nullpointerexception, mockito, resthighlevelclient

I have this method which must be tested:

```
    private void processRequest() {
        BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
        request.add(new IndexRequest("posts").id("1")
                .source(XContentType.JSON,"field", "foo"));
        request.add(new IndexRequest("posts").id("2")
                .source(XContentType.JSON,"field", "bar"));
        final BulkResponse bulkResponse = restHighLevelClient.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

This is what I'm trying to do from my test class:

```
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClientMock = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);

    final String errorMessage = "error message";
    final Exception cause = new Exception("test exception");
    final boolean isFailed = true;
    final int itemID = 0;
    // define the item failure
    BulkItemResponse.Failure failure = mock(BulkItemResponse.Failure.class);
    when(failure.getCause()).thenReturn(cause);
    when(failure.getMessage()).thenReturn(errorMessage);
    // define the item level response
    BulkItemResponse itemResponse = mock(BulkItemResponse.class);
    when(itemResponse.isFailed()).thenReturn(isFailed);
    when(itemResponse.getItemId()).thenReturn(itemID);
    when(itemResponse.getFailure()).thenReturn(failure);
    when(itemResponse.getFailureMessage()).thenReturn("error message");
    List<BulkItemResponse> itemsResponses = Collections.singletonList(itemResponse);
    // define the bulk response to indicate failure
    BulkResponse response = mock(BulkResponse.class);
    when(response.iterator()).thenReturn(itemsResponses.iterator());
    when(response.hasFailures()).thenReturn(isFailed);
    // have the client return the mock response
    when(restHighLevelClientMock.bulk(any(BulkRequest.class), RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(response);
```

I'm getting ***java.lang.NullPointerException*** in this line:

```
when(restHighLevelClientMock.bulk(any(BulkRequest.class), RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(response);
```

Any idea why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too, which led me to this github request:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/40534

Elasticsearc's RestHighLevelClient class marked many of the public methods as final, making it impossible to mock.

There is a workaround detailed in the github page about creating a delegate, which is less than ideal but works.

EDIT: after digging around with possible solutions I found this article: see https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final.  I tried it in my own project and got my tests working with junit jupiter.

Add the following to your src/test/resources folder:

```
mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

add the following line to the org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file:

```
mock-maker-inline
```